# How to test a group of API requests with Gatling in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, testing, gatling

I have an issue that I'm hoping someone can help me with since I'm pretty new to coding and Gatling. I'm using Gatling with Kotlin. I have tried to search on Google and in Gatling documentation, but I have not found any examples on how I should do it.

In my case I have made several different script, each with one scenario. All of the scenarios have steps that are common (for ex. log in, open customer, "then something specific for each script", and then log out). At the moment all the scripts have all the api requests listed. This causes a lot of extra work when a change for the APIs are made, since I then must go and updated it for all the scripts that I have.

So my question is:

How do I take out the common steps (groups of API-requests) in a separate file, so I can use them for all the scenarios where they are needed? so for my scenarios I can refere to that file and select which common steps I want to use? The goal would be that I don't have to update every script when there is a change to an API-request for those common steps, but rather updated it  only one place.

I would love to see some examples if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You should go through the [official tutorials](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/tutorials/) and [online trainings](https://academy.gatling.io/).
They demonstrate how to reuse pieces of scenarios as constants.

Comment: I did not find what I was looking for in the offical tutorials, but the online trainings had an example that was good. It was in "Module 2 - Load Test an eCommerce Solution - Scala", Section C9 - Final Refactor. It can also be found in their git repo https://github.com/gatling/gatling-academy-module-2/tree/20-FrontLine/src/test/scala/gatlingdemostore :)